# module block view only prints if it is on a certain page

Tags: drupal-7

In Drupal 7 Is there a way for me to insert my block into a region only on certain pages inside of a module code? Or do I have to do that in the gui block list?

I've created a banner module, but want to be able to give the ability to choose the pages it appears on. For starts, it could appear only on the front page. I tried a $is_front check, but I am getting an error that $is_front or $variables are undefined.

This doens't work inside of my block_view() function in my module.

```
if ($is_front){
  $block['content'] = theme('mydata', $banner_node_list);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your best bet is to use the block GUI to select where it appears. I can't see any benefits to doing it in the code when it's already built in to be honest.